# Datatable's primefaces loses data after filtering

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, filtering, commandlink

I have a datatable with filtering and a link for selection:

xhtml file:

```
<p:dataTable    value="#{registroNovedadesOcciredMB.servicios}" 
                var="servicio" 
                id="serviciosTbl"
                widgetVar="serviciosTblWV"
                filteredValue="#{registroNovedadesOcciredMB.serviciosFiltro}">
    <p:column headerText="Proveedor" filterBy="#{servicio.nombreProveedor}" filterMatchMode="contains" >
        <p:outputLabel value="#{servicio.nombreProveedor}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Seleccionar"  >
        <p:commandLink  styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-check"                                                                      
                        actionListener="#{registroNovedadesOcciredMB.seleccionarServicio(servicio)}"                            update="form:agregarNovedadPnl,form:serviciosTbl"
                        process="form:serviciosTbl"
                        rendered="#{servicio.estadoOccired == null or ( servicio.estadoOccired != null and ( ! servicio.estadoOccired.codigoEstado.equals('SI') and ! servicio.estadoOccired.codigoEstado.equals('SR')))}"/>    
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

In the bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class RegistroNovedadesOcciredMB {

    private List<ServicioPublicoDTO> servicios ;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        ServicioPublicoEJB servicioPublicoEJB = ServicioPublicoEJB.getInstance();
        servicios = servicioPublicoEJB.consultarServiciosPublicosDisponiblesRegistroNovedades();
    }

    public void seleccionarServicio(ServicioPublicoDTO servicio) {  
        System.out.println(servicio);
    }

    public ServicioPublicoDTO getServicio() {
        return servicio;
    }

    public void setServicio(ServicioPublicoDTO servicio) {
        this.servicio = servicio;
    }

}
```

When I click the link without filter the table, everything works perfect, but when I filtered the table all attributes of servicio are null!!!

Any idea?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Can you show the code of `registroNovedadesOcciredMB`? Especially it's annotations, initialize method and the method `getServicios()`.

Comment: post the code of the bean.

Comment: Done, I added the bean's code